# Sequelize Many to Many table with 3 Primary keys

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have a many to many Enrollment relationship between two tables: Students and Courses like this:

```
var Enrollment = sequelize.define('Enrollment', {
  EnrollmentType: {
    //some attributes
},
{
  associate: function(models){
    models.Person.belongsToMany(models.Course, { as: 'CourseEnroll', through: { model: Enrollment }, foreignKey: 'StudentEnrollId'});
    models.Course.belongsToMany(models.Person, { as: 'StudentEnroll', through: {model: Enrollment},foreignKey: 'CourseEnrollId'});
  }
}
```

But I need to add a third Key from Period Table to have 3 unique key combination on the Enrollment table. I tried doing:

```
Enrollment.belongsTo(models.Period, { as: 'PeriodEnroll', foreignKey: 'PeriodEnrollId', primaryKey: true,});
```

But didn't work, I also tried doing a third belongsToMany with some of the other tables but didn't work. How can I archive this?